# About super in subclass constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I'm trying to use and understand the constructor correct in a subclass. Let's begin with some bits of code:

```
// creating an object
 account = new CreditAccount(accountNumber, personalNumber);

// constructor in superclass Account
public Account(int aNumber, int pNumber) {
accountNumber = aNumber;
personalNumber = pNumber;
}

// constructor in the subclass CreditAccount
public CreditAccount(int aNumber, int pNumber) {
super(accountNumber, personalNumber);
}
```

When I create the new object, `creditAccount`, I send `accountNumber` and `personalNumber` to the constructor in the subclass. But am I doing right? (It's not working!) Am I going to use super in the subclass to get hold of the content of the constructor of the superclass?

Since subclasses only inherits datamembers and method from the superclass and not the constructor, I'm curious how to do this right?

Comment: Did you try inserting some sysout's to know how methods are getting called ?

Comment: The code looks correct. What does "it's not working" mean exactly? What happens that is different from what you expect?

Comment: The code definitely does not look correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't specify what isn't working, so I assume it is the simple invokation error:

```
public CreditAccount(int aNumber, int pNumber) {
   super(accountNumber, personalNumber);
}
```

you should invoke the `super()` with the relevant parametrs, which are the input of the derived class` constructor:

```
public CreditAccount(int aNumber, int pNumber) {
   super(aNumber, pNumber);
}
```

Comment: Aha! It seems like that little error was the problem! So by doing this, I don't need to add something more to the construtor in the subclass like the variables in the superclass constructor: accountNumber = aNumber; When I'm using these values in the subclass, which variables am I going to use? The accountNumber or aNumber?
personalNumber = pNumber;
??

Comment: @3D-kreativ: everything done by the superclass' constructor is going to be done by invoking `super()`, You only need to do the additional ops, specific for this derived class. In your example, you don't need to set personalNumber and accountNumber again in the derived class' constructor.